# PHP mail() errors: Hide attempted email but still show error

Tags: php, email

I am working on a 'forgot password' form, currently I am working locally so the mail function will not work but the errors come up like this:

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in ...  on line 508
Error Sending Email - mail@email.com, Password Reset,
You have requested your password to be reset. To login, use the username and password below:

Username: admin
Password: azurapura
...
```

Obviously, if the mail function does not work I wouldn't want someone to see the message/password unless it is through their mail. Is there a way to disable that part of the error from showing or is there a way to customize the error for this function?

I saw [a post to create error handlers](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_error.asp) however, this seems like it only applies to types of errors (warnings...)

Comment: ::FACEPALM::
My mail function ended with:  or die("Error Sending Email - $emailto, $subject, $message, $header_data");

duh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply prefix the `mail` with an email-sign (can't type one here!). This way PHP supresses the error. Futher info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Answer (score 0):

I *really* recommend you have display_errors turned off on your production machine.

`mail` returns a boolean value telling if the message was accepted for delivery or not. Use that to detect errors.